# Can you run Coldfusion and PHP side by side

Tags: php, wordpress, coldfusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is is possible to run Coldfusion & PHP on the same server and website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444598/is-is-possible-to-run-coldfusion-php-on-the-same-server-and-website)

I have a client with an old cold fusion site that has some cloud applications that they would like to keep.

We are building a new site for them using WordPress and I am wondering if I can run LAMP side by side with the ColdFusion apps so we don't have to re-write their applications (this is not a requirement of the project).

Thanks.

Comment: How are those CF apps deployed?

Comment: The question is vague at this point.

Comment: @ itachi, yes this is a vague question, we are at the beginning of this project and I am just looking for a little info as to if this is possible, which it seems to be.  We are looking at all options at this point.

Comment: @shiplu, the CF apps are installed in a protected subdirectory, one option may be to simply use a different hosting account for the front end site while preserving the CF apps and redirecting URLs.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can run PHP & ColdFusion on the same server. I have my server configured that way.

Comment: Could you point me towards some documentation on this, I am not a CF developer.  Thanks.

Comment: If you google any documentation regarding setting up CF on your apache or IIS server you simply need to do those steps, in addition to the PHP steps you have already configured.  There should be no concern of conflict between the two as CF has it's own module to tie into Apache and IIS.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Installing/coldfusion_9_install.pdf and http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "Yes".

The longer answer is "Yes, and as long as you have IIS or Apache configured correctly to handle the different file extensions, you shouldn't have an issue."

I've set up dev environments with both without an issue, even sharing the same database, even with a nodeJS application running alongside.

If you let us know what your current config is, it will be easier to help you get both running together.

Comment: thank you, I am working on getting the current server info now, and will be back (maybe in a few weeks) as we get closer to launching this.

Comment: It maybe best to have the current information first, and get the environment running before doing any code.