# ColdFusion and PHP on the same computer, different environments

Tags: php, coldfusion, wamp

I currently have CF 8, and I want to be able to use PHP code also, but in a separate environment. I don't want CF and PHP code intermingling.

I have downloaded WAMP in order to accomplish this, but I can't get it to start (it's just Orange in the task bar).

Why is WAMP in the Orange? On previous installations, I start it, and it turns green. Does this have something to do with CF? When I go to localhost, I go to my CF environment. How do I get to the WAMP localhost?

Comment: Related: [Is is possible to run Coldfusion & PHP on the same server and website?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2444598) and its duplicate: [Can you run Coldfusion and PHP side by side](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11634660)

Comment: Check the log files for error messages.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I went to the WAMP icon > Apache > Apache error log, and it says the file doesn't exist. Is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: Haven't a clue; I don't use WAMP. This sounds like a WAMP problem, and nothing to do with CF. Have you checked the WAMP docs/troubleshooting for these symptoms?

Comment: _"When I go to localhost, I go to my CF environment"_ - CF doesn't run on port 80 (unless you tell it to); so it sounds like you have an existing web server (IIS?) in the picture. CF and PHP can both work with Apache or IIS - pick one.

Comment: if you have cf running with iis it will be using port 80, wamp will likely fail to start because it can not bind to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I have ColdFusion and PHP running on my Windows development machine and my production Linux server. I do not recall having a whole lot of trouble doing so either.

Before the StackOverLords flag this question for being too broad, try narrowing the focus of the question and you will be more likely to get answers that will help you.

Comment: Ok, narrowed my questions. Hope this doesn't get closed. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, still didn't work. Perhaps it has something to do with the C++ Visual Studio thing it said I had to download? How much does that effect WAMP?

Comment: My suggestion would be to uninstall everything. Then install WAMP and make sure its running the way you expect. Once that is done, install ColdFusion - but do NOT configure web serer during install (I have had issues with this in past) - choose 'built in' web server. Once CF is installed and running, run the Web Server Config tool to configure Apache to use ColdFusion

Comment: Unfortunately, uninstalling CF is not an option. I'm working with the systems team to solve this. They said the same thing as everyone else, that I shouldn't have a problem, but we are still unable to get it. When we figure it out I'll post it here. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a virtual machine as your separate environment if you are really concerned - In which case it would be the normal installation procedure.

However, I cannot think of any reason why having them both installed together would cause you problems (I have had numerous set-ups with them running in parallel on both on Linux and windows systems with Apache and IIS)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue. I believe what I did was set the CF application server to start manually with Windows as a service. Try disabling CF, restart the computer and if WAMP is running ok you should be able to start CF without issue. IF that works you could probably autostart with delay to avoid having to do it manually each time. I generally don't work in both environments at the same time so it ends up just using extra resources anyway.